# How to make a custom url for a file in electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I am trying to build a mini browser using Electron.js. Is it possible to make urls like chrome://settings or about:config, so that when the user goes to that link I can show an html file? I basically want to associate a url with a file in electron.

Comment: I assume you have the `.html` file on disk, so is what you're saying: "How can I redirect the user to `file:///electron/path/here/test.html` when they try going to: `chrome://settings`"?

Comment: @Joshua yes that is what I'm trying to achieve, but in the devtools and everywhere else I want it to be shown as `chrome://settings`

Comment: What sort of places do you mean by "everywhere else"?

Comment: I mean like wherever if i try to get the src of the window or if I type `location.href` in dev tools I want to see `chrome://settings`, like in actual browsers

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that, though if you have your own HTML url bar then you can change the url bar to say whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little searching at npm, I found a package that does exactly what I want, it's [electron protocols](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-protocols). It's a simple way to add custom protolcs in Electron, Here's an example"

```
const protocols = require('electron-protocols');
const path = require('path');    
protocols.register('browser', uri => {
   let base = app.getAppPath();
      if(uri.hostname == "newtab"){
            return path.join(base,"newtab.html")
      }
 });
```

In this example, if you go to the link browser://newtab, it opens newtab.html. And if you type `location.href` the DevTools it shows browser://newtab there too

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), and base64-encode the contents of your data as a link. You can [use Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) to encode and decode binary data, then you just specify the MIME type at the start.

If you go to the following URL in a browser for example you'll see a `png` decoded and rendered:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

The MDN Web doc in the first link mentions the process of base64 encoding an HTML file.

Alternatively, if you just want to force the download of a link you could [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) the `download` attribute to your anchor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I meant. What I want is when the user goes to a page like `chrome://settings`, I want to show a file like setttings.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `did-start-navigation` to detect when they go to `chrome://settings/` then intercept that and tell it to go to `https://stackoverflow.com/` instead.

Here's the code:

```
mainWin.webContents.on('did-start-navigation', function (evt, navigateUrl) {
    if (navigateUrl == 'chrome://settings/') {
        evt.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function () { // Without this it just crashes, no idea why.
            mainWin.loadURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

<sub>I tried the `will-navigate` event, but it didn't work.</sub>

[Docs for: `did-start-navigation`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-start-navigation)